# Azure DevOps API pipelinePermissions resourceType infos

Tags: api, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

No precise information on the "resourceType" usable with the YAML pipeline security API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/pipeline-permissions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP

[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/pipelinepermissions/{resourceType}/{resourceId}?api-version=7.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/pipelines/pipelinepermissions/%7BresourceType%7D/%7BresourceId%7D?api-version=7.0-preview.1)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the resourceType of one pipeline through REST API [Resources - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/resources/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0).

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}/resources?api-version=7.0-preview.1
```

You can get the definitionId in the URL after clicking your target pipeline from the pipeline list.

[image]

Then you can see something like below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I analyzed the requests send by the web interface and found the missing info:

[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/pipelinepermissions/{resourceType}/{resourceId}?api-version=7.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/pipelines/pipelinepermissions/%7BresourceType%7D/%7BresourceId%7D?api-version=7.0-preview.1)

resourceType:

- repository
- endpoint
- variablegroup
- environment
- queue